# Efficiently synchronizing a list in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, list, concurrency

I have a list and a particular operation can affect 4 nodes - current, previous, next and head. Is there any way I can lock this operation so that rest of the list entries are free to be accessed and changed ?

I tried finding out if one can obtain a lock of multiple list entries but not able to find anything.

PS: This is my first day in life playing with concurrency and multi threading.

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't attempt to do this on my first day.  Just take a lock on the entire list.

Comment: This is not a code that I pushing in production.:) I am just learning and trying to get a feel of things. I helps to find answers to questions even if they are not rational. :)

Comment: So could you perhaps provide a bit more context in your question then?  I find it hard to provide an answer unless you are looking for “here is the code”-style answers which I believe you are not.  You should be fairly familiar with how synchronization works in general in Java before attempting a selective locking.  Can you share your current attempt to let us see what you have tried and where it fails?

Comment: If all operations require a lock on head, then locking  it is effectively equivalent to locking the whole list. So, what's the point?

Comment: @Dima. That is a very good point. So how about if we just want to lock on three nodes other than head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is, probably, to use indexes of the nodes (keep a bitset, indicating which nodes are currently locked), but that would break if you also want to concurrently add or remove nodes to the (middle of) the list. If that is not the requirement, then, perhaps, you should revisit the "lock by index" idea.

Meanwhile, consider something like this:

```
class NodeLocker {
    HashSet<Node> lockedNodes = new HashSet();
    protected boolean tryLock(List<Node> nodes) {                   
        for(n: Nodes) {
            if(lockedNodes.contains(n)) return false;
        }
        lockedNodes.addAll(nodes);
        return true;
    }
    public synchronized void lock(Node ... nodes) throws InterruptedException {
        while(!tryLock(Arrays.asList(nodes))) wait();
    }
    public synchronized void unlock(Node ... nodes) {
        lockedNodes.removeAll(Arrays.asList(nodes));
        notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a bitmapped set, the program could use an _isLocked_ field on each node.

Comment: Yeah, but there are two problems with it. First, you would have to modify the underlying structure, that may not even be possible and/or sensible. And second navigating the linked list to atomically lock several nodes is kinda cumbersome, and may get really inefficient, especially if you wanted to lock a set of nodes that are not directly  linked to each other.